# Select cell from same column with MAX function

Tags: mysql, group-by

Table for example:

```
event_id| group_id | updated_at
1 | 1 |2012-01-02
2 | 1 |2012-01-01
3 | 2 |2012-01-01
4 | 2 |2012-01-02
5 | 3 |2012-01-01
```

I need select all event_id with max date, grouped by group_id. So right result will be:

```
event_id| group_id | updated_at
1 | 1 |2012-01-02
4 | 2 |2012-01-02
5 | 3 |2012-01-01
```

Can I select event_id, from the same row that MAX(updated_at) has been selected?

```
SELECT event_id, group_id, MAX(updated_at) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL may allow the type of syntax you suggest - specifying non-aggregate columns that are also not part of the group by - but it is non-standard and IMHO a bad habit to get into.

Instead, you would do:

```
SELECT t1.event_id, t1.group_id, t1.updated_at
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS max_updated_at
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY group_id
) t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id AND t1.updated_at = t2.max_updated_at
```

Note though if `updated_at` is non-unique for a given `group_id`, this query will return all of said rows.

Comment: So what would you like to do?

Comment: I have one idea, to use ORDER BY in subquery, and than use GROUP BY, I think i'll get that I want but this query will be very bad practices

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution by lc, the following would allow you to get the records for the latest day, and then the one with the highest event_id per day for those records:-

```
SELECT t1.event_id, t1.group_id, t1.updated_at
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS max_updated_at
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY group_id
) t2 
ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id AND t1.updated_at = t2.max_updated_at
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT group_id, updated_at, MAX(event_id) AS max_event_id
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY group_id, updated_at
) t3 
ON t1.group_id = t3.group_id 
AND t1.event_id = t2.max_event_id
AND t3.max_updated_at = t3.updated_at
```